# Values in picklist not displaying

Tags: custom-object, picklist

I added additional values to a pick list via the admin setup screen. The old values still appear when opening the pick list on the object but I do not see the newly added values.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have recordtypes on the object? If so you may need to update the pick lists for each record type to show the new values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using recordype then assign those newly added values to that recordtype.